# an efficient way to convert an array of arrays to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a function that takes in 2 parameters: 
an array **csvFields:**

```
["id","name","age",...]
```

and another array of arrays **csvRows** which contains the data for those fields:

```
 [["1", "john", "10"],["2", "Jane", "11"],["3", "John Doe", "12"],...]
```

What this function outputs is an array of objects like this:

```
[{id: "1", name: "john", age: "10"},{id: 2", name: "jane", age: "11"},{id: "3", name: "John doe", age: "12"}, ...]
```

and here's the function:

```js
const arrayOfArraysToArrayOfObjects = (csvFields, csvRows) => {
        const data = csvRows.map((row) => {
            let obj = {};
            csvFields.forEach((field, index) => {
                obj[field] = row[index];
            });
            return obj;
        });
        return data;
    };


    const csvFields = ["id","name","age"];
    const csvRows = [["1", "john", "10"],["2", "Jane", "11"],["3", "John Doe", "12"]];
    const data = arrayOfArraysToArrayOfObjects(csvFields, csvRows);
    console.log(data);
```

The problem is that this function is not really efficient and gets really slow when it comes to big csv files with alot of rows. Also, the fields can vary for different csv files which is why i have to keep it all dynamic.

Is there any way to make this function more efficient?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cycles more faster than methods, see benchmark:
 https://jsperf.com/my-test321321321

```js
const arrayOfArraysToArrayOfObjects = (csvFields, csvRows) => {
  let res = []

  for (let arr of csvRows) {
    let obj = {}
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      obj[csvFields[i]] = arr[i]

    }
    res.push(obj)
  }

  return res;
};


const csvFields = ["id","name","age"];
const csvRows = [["1", "john", "10"],["2", "Jane", "11"],["3", "John Doe", "12"]];
const data = arrayOfArraysToArrayOfObjects(csvFields, csvRows);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible improvement would be to iterate over the *large* array (the `csvRows`) just once, rather than iterate over the *smaller* array (`csvRows`) once. Also, you might use `for` loops instead, which have slightly less overhead (but are less readable) than array methods, and so might be more performant with huge files:

```js
const arrayOfArraysToArrayOfObjects = (csvFields, csvRows) => {
  const rowLen = csvRows.length;
  const fieldLen = csvFields.length;
  const results = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < rowLen; i++) {
    const row = csvRows[i];
    const obj = {};
    for (let j = 0; j < fieldLen; j++) {
      obj[csvFields[j]] = row[j];
    }
    results.push(obj);
  }
  return results;
};

const csvFields = ["id", "name", "age"];
const csvRows = [
  ["1", "john", "10"],
  ["2", "Jane", "11"],
  ["3", "John Doe", "12"]
];
const data = arrayOfArraysToArrayOfObjects(csvFields, csvRows);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and spread single key/value objects.

```js
const
    arrayOfArraysToArrayOfObjects = (csvFields, csvRows) => 
        csvRows.map(row => Object.assign(...csvFields.map((k, i) => ({ [k]: row[i] })))),
    csvFields = ["id", "name", "age"],
    csvRows = [["1", "john", "10"], ["2", "Jane", "11"], ["3", "John Doe", "12"]],
    data = arrayOfArraysToArrayOfObjects(csvFields, csvRows);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```